# Mongodb use or skip a $match based on a condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Im developping a web apllication and i couldnt manage to use a $match after a condition
so basicly what i wan'to do, if the user is an admin i skip the $match and if the user is not an admin i match data based in the logged in user.

This is was my attempt:

```
{ $cond: { if: currentuser != Admin, then:{ $match: { state: currentuser } } } },
```

But it didn't work and i got this error :

```
MongoServerError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$cond'
```

and this is the whole code :

```
    exports.allsstates = async (req, res) => {
    
    currentuser = JSON.parse(atob(req.headers.authorization.split('.')[1])).role;
    
    try {
        const allstate = await Users.aggregate(
            [

                {
                   
                         $cond:{ if:{ $eq: [currentuser, 'Admin']} ,then:{  $match: { state: currentbase }}}   ,
                    
                },
{
    $lookup:
                    {
                        from: "types",
                        localField: "type",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "type"
                    }
                },
                {
                    $set: {
                        type: "$type.type",
                    }
                },
   { $match: { type: "x" } },
   { $match: { situation: "y" }}
          ]
        )

        res.json(allstate);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
    }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know if current user is Admin before the aggregation starts? If so you can just conditionally add the pipeline stage at first place. Can you share some more code like complete pipeline and where you can check user is admin?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes i know actually before the aggregation i call the user role and affect it to "currentuser",i added the pipeline stage at first place but still same problem i update the question with whole aggregation take a look now if you dont mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically construct the pipeline.  For clarity, start with the "constant" part i.e. the stages you always run, then use if/then/else to prepend a `$match`:

```js
var pipeline = [
{$lookup: {
    from: "types",
    localField: "type",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "type"
}},
{$set: { type: "$type.type" }}, 

{$match: { type: "x", situation: "y" }} // 2 $match stages combined into 1 for efficiency...
          
];

if(currentuser != "admin") {
    // Prepend a $match condition:
    pipeline.unshift({$match: {state: currentuser}});
}
Users.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: Actually there is other stages in the pipeline so thats why i wanted to do the match inside the aggregation

Comment: i updated the code in the question

Comment: Answer updated.  Basically, same answer except now `$match` gets prepended to the pipeline.

Comment: ok thank you so much i will try it